# Spring Design By Contract: where to start?

Tags: spring

I am trying to put a "Contract" on a method call. My web application is in Spring 3.

Is writing customs Annotations the right way to go. If so, any pointers( I didn't find anything in spring reference docs).

Should I use tools like "Modern Jass", JML ...? Again any pointers will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracts for Java which is based on Modern Jass is one way to write contracts.

http://code.google.com/p/cofoja/

As per the writing of this reply, this is pretty basic. Hopefully this will improve as we go on.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) could get you most of the way. Spring security defines the **@PreAuthorize** annotation which is fired before method invocation and allows you to use Spring 3's new expression engine, such as:

```
@PreAuthorize("#customerId > 0")
public Customer getCustomer(int customerId) { .. }
```

or far more advanced rules like the following which ensures that the passed **user** does not have role **ADMIN**.

```
@PreAuthorize("#user.role != T(com.company.Role).ADMIN)")
public void saveUser(User user) { .. }
```

You can also provide default values for your contract with the @Value annotation

```
public Customer getCustomer(@Value("#{434}") int customerId) { .. }
```

You can even reference system properties in your value expressions.

Setting up Spring security for this purpose is not to hard as you can just create a [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) that grants some default role to all users. Alternatively you could make you own custom Spring aspect and then let this use the [SpelExpressionParser](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/SpelExpressionParser.html) to check method values.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind writing some parts of your Java web application in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) (which is possible with Spring) I would suggest using [GContracts](http://github.com/andresteingress/gcontracts).

GContracts is a Design by Contract (tm) library entirely written in Java - without any dependencies to other libraries - and has full support for class invariants, pre- and postconditions and inheritance of those assertions.

Comment: I like this solution, but groovy is stretch for us in our present dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an ideal solution to this, interestingly it is a planned feature for the Spring framework (2.0 implemented patch):

http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2698

The best thing I suggest to use JSR 303 which is for bean validation.  AFAIK there are two implementations for this:

- [Agimatec Validations](http://code.google.com/p/agimatec-validation/)
- [Hibernate Validator](https://www.hibernate.org/412.html)

There's a guide here for integrating it into Spring, I haven't followed it through but it looks ok:

http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/

Comment: Is "Validation Rule" same as a Contract? As per your answer, you are using both of them interchangeably. 

The problem with the validation rule you have suggested above is that it cannot be configured for a method call.

Comment: Adding bean validation on an field/method/class level is a way of introducing DBC precondition checks into your application.  Are you trying to do more than that?

Comment: I am trying to put a contract -- like verify the input of method call is not null, and it has specific value on a method call. I call it contract because this contract should be invoked every time the call to the method happens.

I see that in the validation frameworks the validation is not used with AOP, which makes me doubt if we can use validation as a contract.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend C4J for 2 reasons:

- It has **Eclipse plugin** so you don't need to manually configure it.
- The documentation is written in a clear, structured format so you can easily use it.

Her's the [link to C4J](http://c4j-team.github.io/C4J/)